# What's the equivalent of `pandas.Series.map(json.loads)` in polars?

Tags: pandas, python-polars, rust-polars

Based on the document of polars, one can use `json_path_match` to extract JSON fields into string series.

But can we do something like `pandas.Series.map(json.loads)` to convert the whole JSON string at once? One can then further convert the loaded JSON series into another dataframe with sane dtypes.

I know I can do it first in `pandas`, but I'm looking for a way in `polars`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should first point out that there is a [`polars.read_json`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_json.html) method.  For example:

```py
import polars as pl
import io

json_file = """[{"a":"1", "b":10, "c":[1,2,3]},
{"a":"2", "b":20, "c":[3,4,5]},
{"a":"3.1", "b":30.2, "c":[8,8,8]},
{"a":"4", "b":40.0, "c":[9,9,90]}]
"""

pl.read_json(io.StringIO(json_file))
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c          │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---        │
│ str ┆ f64  ┆ list [i64] │
╞═════╪══════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10.0 ┆ [1, 2, 3]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 20.0 ┆ [3, 4, 5]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.1 ┆ 30.2 ┆ [8, 8, 8]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 40.0 ┆ [9, 9, 90] │
└─────┴──────┴────────────┘
```

But to answer your specific question about JSON data already loaded into a Series, I think what you're looking for is the [`polars.Series.apply`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Series.apply.html) method, which will apply a callable function to each cell of a Polars Series.

For example, let's say we have the following JSON fields already loaded into a Series in a Polars DataFrame:

```py
import json
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "json_val": [
            '{"a":"1", "b":10, "c":[1,2,3]}',
            '{"a":"2", "b":20, "c":[3,4,5]}',
            '{"a":"3.1", "b":30.2, "c":[8,8,8]}',
            '{"a":"4", "b":40.0, "c":[9,9,90]}',
        ]
    }
)
print(df)
```

```
shape: (4, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ json_val                            │
│ ---                                 │
│ str                                 │
╞═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ {"a":"1", "b":10, "c":[1,2,3]}      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"a":"2", "b":20, "c":[3,4,5]}      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"a":"3.1", "b":30.2, "c":[8,8,8... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"a":"4", "b":40.0, "c":[9,9,90]... │
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

We can use `apply` and the `json.loads` function.  In this example, that will yield a Series of type `struct`:

```py
df.select(pl.col("json_val").apply(json.loads))
```

```
shape: (4, 1)
┌──────────────────────────┐
│ json_val                 │
│ ---                      │
│ struct[3]{'a', 'b', 'c'} │
╞══════════════════════════╡
│ {"1",10,[1, 2, 3]}       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"2",20,[3, 4, 5]}       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"3.1",30,[8, 8, 8]}     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"4",40,[9, 9, 90]}      │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

(One caution, notice how column `b` has been truncated to an integer.)

Depending on the structure of your JSON, you may be able to also use the [`polars.DataFrame.unnest`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) function to split the `json_val` struct column into separate columns.

```py
df.select(pl.col("json_val").apply(json.loads)).unnest("json_val")
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c          │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ str ┆ i64 ┆ list [i64] │
╞═════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ [1, 2, 3]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 20  ┆ [3, 4, 5]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.1 ┆ 30  ┆ [8, 8, 8]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 40  ┆ [9, 9, 90] │
└─────┴─────┴────────────┘
```

Does this help get you started?

##### Edit: handling type-conversion issues

One general strategy that I use with any un-typed input file (especially csv files) is to return all values as a string/`polars.Utf8` type.  That way, I can explicitly convert types later, after I've had a chance to visually inspect the results.  (I've been burned too often by "automatic" type conversions.)

The [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.loads) method has two helpful keyword options `parse_float` and `parse_int` that will help in this case.  We can use a simple lambda function to tell the json parser to leave integer and float columns as strings.

```py
# define our own translate function to keep floats/ints as strings
def json_translate(json_str: str):
    return json.loads(json_str, parse_float=lambda x: x, parse_int=lambda x: x)

df.select(pl.col("json_val").apply(f=json_translate))
```

```
shape: (4, 1)
┌────────────────────────────────┐
│ json_val                       │
│ ---                            │
│ struct[3]{'a', 'b', 'c'}       │
╞════════════════════════════════╡
│ {"1","10",["1", "2", "3"]}     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"2","20",["3", "4", "5"]}     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"3.1","30.2",["8", "8", "8"]} │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ {"4","40.0",["9", "9", "90"]}  │
└────────────────────────────────┘
```

Notice that all the integer and float values are left as strings, and remain so when we use the `unnest` function (the column headers below show "str").

```py
df.select(pl.col("json_val").apply(f=json_translate)).unnest('json_val')
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬──────────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c                │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---              │
│ str ┆ str  ┆ list [str]       │
╞═════╪══════╪══════════════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10   ┆ ["1", "2", "3"]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2   ┆ 20   ┆ ["3", "4", "5"]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3.1 ┆ 30.2 ┆ ["8", "8", "8"]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4   ┆ 40.0 ┆ ["9", "9", "90"] │
└─────┴──────┴──────────────────┘
```

From this point, you can use Polars' [`cast`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.cast.html) expression to convert the strings to the specific numeric types that you want.  Here's a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71790235/polars-switching-between-dtypes-within-a-dataframe) that can help with the `cast`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I did search `map` but missed `apply`. Why does the mentioned caution happen in polars but not in pandas?

Comment: Or can I specify `b` a float type?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include a strategy for dealing with type conversion issues.

Comment: I believe automatic casting returns `b` as an integer because in the first row, the value of `b` is `10`, rather than `10.0` or something that looks like a float.  But we can get past this by importing all values as strings, and converting in a later step, once the data is in a Polars DataFrame.

Comment: I found that polars failed to load JSON array strings like `pl.DataFrame({"json_val": ['[{"x": 1, "y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 4}]']})` (but works for `'[]'`) using `apply`, do you have any idea of this? Thanks.

Comment: For `[{"x": 1, "y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 4}]`, `json.loads` returns a `list of dictionaries` .  The Polars `apply` method, however, cannot convert this list of dictionaries to a column in the Polars DataFrame.  You may want to log a GitHub issue to see if/how the `apply` method can support this.

Answer (score 1):

now there's a native function for extracting json strings within a column to `struct`:

```
df.select(pl.col("json_val").str.json_extract())
```